# How to create two type of application bar in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, application-bar

I already create the application bar in my application.

Now i want create new application bar with exist of old one is present.

Is it possible or not?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is difficult to understand what actually you mean by `i want create new application bar with exist of old one is present`. Could you please clarify?

Comment: sorry, my question is any possible for create two application bar in same page or application.

Comment: Do you want to switch between 2 application bars, or are you try to show two application bars at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use standard [`Application Bar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) component - answer is **no**.

But you could create your own UI element, which will implement Application Bar behavior and just double it.

But before you start, do you really need to create two appbars? I think that most of users will not understand how to use them.

Comment: Also you can reuse Application Bar for resources with minimal overhead like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394043(v=vs.105).aspx)